# model.fit() generates "NoneType object is not callable" error, any debugging tips?

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8ooK.png)

this is the error I see, Using transformer chatbot tutorial from https://medium.com/tensorflow/a-transformer-chatbot-tutorial-with-tensorflow-2-0-88bf59e66fe2
I converted Model subclassing classes(Positional encoding, Multi Headed attention layers) into function, so that I can save my model as h5 file.
I changed "Positional encoding, custom training, multi-headed-attention-layers" classes into function with this code:
For the sake of checking code is converted rightly or not just sharing multi headed attention layer

```
#MULTI HEADED ATTENTION LAYER
def split_heads(inputs, batch_size, num_heads, d_model):
  depth = d_model // num_heads
  inputs = tf.reshape(inputs, shape=(batch_size, -1, num_heads, depth))
  return tf.transpose(inputs, perm=[0, 2, 1, 3])


def call(d_model, num_heads, inputs):
  query, key, value, mask = inputs['query'], inputs['key'], inputs[
        'value'], inputs['mask']
  batch_size = tf.shape(query)[0]
  depth = d_model // num_heads

    # linear layers
  query = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=d_model)(query)
  key = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=d_model)(key)
  value = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=d_model)(value)

    # split heads
  query = split_heads(query, batch_size, num_heads, d_model)
  key = split_heads(key, batch_size, num_heads, d_model)
  value = split_heads(value, batch_size, num_heads, d_model)

    # scaled dot-product attention
  scaled_attention = scaled_dot_product_attention(query, key, value, mask)

  scaled_attention = tf.transpose(scaled_attention, perm=[0, 2, 1, 3])

    # concatenation of heads
  concat_attention = tf.reshape(scaled_attention,
                                  (batch_size, -1, d_model))

  dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=d_model)

    # final linear layer
  outputs = dense(concat_attention)

  return outputs
```

its equivalent to the code mentioned in transformer chatbot tutorial link mentioned above.
I needed transformer chatbot mechanism on mobile android device ultimately.